analog of setdiff() using regular expressions
Suppose I want to exclude values matching a series of regular expressions from a character vector, in the same way that I would use setdiff() for fixed character strings, e.g.
value <- c("apple pie", "cat", "dog", "dogmatic", "no apples")
re_setdiff(value, c("^apple", "^dog"))
## desired results:
value[c(2,5)]
[1] "cat"       "no apples"

I know how I can code this by brute force (see my answer) but am wondering if there's a more efficient/more idiomatic way to do it (maybe something in stringi/stringr?), or something that's already in a (widely used) package?

You are right that it can be done by Reduce
> value <- c("apple pie", "cat", "dog", "dogmatic", "no apples")

> exclude <- c("^apple", "^dog")

> Reduce(\(x, y) grep(y, x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE), exclude, value)
[1] "cat"       "no apples"

Benchmarking
jofrhwld <- \(value, exclude) {
    str_subset(
        value,
        # concat into 1 regex
        pattern = str_c(exclude, collapse = "|"),
        negate = TRUE
    )
}

tic <- \(value, exclude) {
    Reduce(\(x, y) grep(y, x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE), exclude, value)
}

darrentsai <- \(value, exclude) {
    value[!rowSums(sapply(exclude, grepl, value))]
}

benbolker <- function(x, y, ...) {
    for (yy in y) {
        x <- grep(yy, x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE, ...)
    }
    return(x)
}

microbenchmark(
    jofrhwld = jofrhwld(value, exclude),
    tic = tic(value, exclude),
    darrentsai = darrentsai(value, exclude),
    benbolker = benbolker(value, exclude),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equal"
)

shows
Unit: relative
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   jofrhwld 3.298173 3.365282 4.302031 3.267003 4.027422 11.35689   100
        tic 1.326923 1.334713 3.154308 1.366346 1.429391 14.58037   100
 darrentsai 2.548269 2.761838 3.840466 2.606786 2.723790 17.21892   100
  benbolker 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.00000   100


Thanks, I didn't know about unit = "relative" before ...

HI, inspired by your benchmark, I ran another one on a larger vector. It seems that concatenating a regex via | (as JoFrhwld did) is a better approach for that case.

Here's the brute-force solution:
re_setdiff <- function(x, y, ...) {
   for (yy in y) {
      x <- grep(yy, x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE, ...)
   }
   return(x)
}

I've left ... there in case someone wants to specify e.g. perl=TRUE. (I guess this could also be done more compactly/inscrutably with Reduce() ... ?)

I think your for-loop dynamic updating is good enough (+1), see my benchmarking. But, more investigation is needed if you care about the speed, since it really depends on the cardinalities of value and exclude sets.

I ran another benchmark on a larger vector. It seems that concatenating a regex via | (as JoFrhwld did) is a great choice for that case.

This isn't an answer to your question "if there's a more efficient/more idiomatic way to do it".

With stringr, you could make use of str_subset().
value <- c("apple pie", "cat", "dog", "dogmatic", "no apples")

exclude <- c("^apple", "^dog")

str_subset(
  value,
  # concat into 1 regex
  pattern = str_c(exclude, collapse = "|"),
  negate = TRUE
)

#> [1] "cat"       "no apples"


Interesting question what the efficiency/scaling difference is between processing sequentially vs concatenating a regex via | ...

An option of sequential elimination is to use sapply with grepl.
value[!rowSums(sapply(exclude, grepl, value))]

# [1] "cat"       "no apples"


Another choice is to use recursion:
recur_diff <- function(x, pattern) {
  if(length(pattern) == 0) return(x)
  recur_diff(grep(pattern[1], x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE), pattern[-1])
}

recur_diff(value, exclude)
# [1] "cat"       "no apples"


Benchmark
I carried out a benchmark with a larger vector and more patterns.
N <- 5000
M <- 50

value <- replicate(N, paste(sample(LETTERS, 10), collapse = ''))
exclude <- replicate(M, paste(sample(LETTERS, 3), collapse = ''))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  jofrhwld = jofrhwld(value, exclude),
  tic = tic(value, exclude),
  darren_sapply = darrentsai(value, exclude),
  darren_recur = recur_diff(value, exclude),
  benbolker = benbolker(value, exclude),
  unit = "relative",
  check = "equal"
)

Unit: relative
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
      jofrhwld 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100  a 
           tic 3.342135 3.321231 3.339698 3.320279 3.309806 3.481526   100   b
 darren_sapply 3.356324 3.343180 3.356167 3.345018 3.328611 3.592255   100   b
  darren_recur 3.362487 3.343806 3.361479 3.346198 3.336437 3.462555   100   b
     benbolker 3.357269 3.336147 3.358892 3.340248 3.322553 3.506824   100   b


Thanks for the interesting benchmarking! Yes, the speed really depends on the sizes of two sets.
